# Access Denied 400 when copy S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My lambda tries to copy a S3 object, but does not work.

Code:

```
import { escapeUriPath } from '@aws-sdk/util-uri-escape';
import { S3Client, CopyObjectCommandInput, CopyObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const handler = () => {
  const path = escapeUriPath('All Files/documents/folder with space/test');
  const CopySource = escapeUriPath('my_bucket/All Files/documents/folder with space/test_rename');
  copyS3Object({
   Bucket: 'my_bucket',
   Key: path,
   CopySource
  })
}

export const copyS3Object = async (input: CopyObjectCommandInput) => {
  const command = new CopyObjectCommand(input);
  return await s3Client.send(command);
};
```

An error I see in CloudWatch which is not quite helpful

```
        "Code": "AccessDenied",
        "name": "AccessDenied",
        "$fault": "client",
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 400,
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        }
```

The interesting part is that:

- I already set s3 policy to allow `s3:*` action on the bucket
- I am able to use the same lambda to upload/delete an object, but not copy

What could cause the `AccessDenied` error?

Comment: What do you mean by "set s3 policy"? Are you referring to a Bucket Policy on the S3 bucket? The preferred method is to put the S3 permissions in the IAM Role that is associated with the AWS Lambda function. Please show us the policy that you used.

Comment: Is the function able to `GetObject()` on that same 'source' object? I'm just wondering whether the issue is with the source object itself.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. It is totally my fault.

The policy resource should be `"Resource": ["my_bucket", "my_bucket/*"]`, instead of `"Resource": ["my_bucket"]`

The full policy:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "create-lambda-policy" {
  name = local.lambda_policy_name
  path = "/"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": ["my_bucket", "my_bucket/*"],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```